# Anchor tag inside an <li> event triggering issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a horizontal menu plugin in which i am adding anchor tag to the `<li>` in order to get the menu items. i am using onmouseover event  of anchor tag to get the menu items list. my problem is whenever i am moving mouse over the content i am getting the submenu (ie, the event gets fired) but if i move the mouse on the empty space on the right side of the menu item then the event is not triggering ,when used firebug i found that empty space is belongs to the parent container which is `<li>`.I cannot use onmouseover of `<li>` since my logic is different.I just want to expand the size of my anchor tag to the parent `<li>`. please give me a solution.

```
<li class="">
    <a href="#" class="accessible" onmouseover="loadSublevelMenu('${url}','${menuVar}',event);">${menuName}&raquo;</a>
</li>
```

Comment: make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: why you cannot use onmouseover of `<li>` tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to the a tag `style="display:block"`